# Maximization of the determinant of $C(x) := B^T A(x) B$

Tags: matrices, optimization, determinant

Given matrix-valued function $A : \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ and (tall) matrix $B \in \Bbb R^{n \times m}$, where $n \gt m$, let matrix-valued function $C : \Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^{m \times m}$ be defined by

$$ C(x) := B^T A(x) B $$

I would like to maximize the determinant of $C(x)$ without directly considering $C(x)$. If I maximize the determinant of $A(x)$, does that maximize the determinant of $C(x)$ as well?

If it were $m = n$, then we would have:

$$\det(C) = \det(B)^2 \det(A)$$

Hence, maximising $\det(A)$ would maximize as a consequence $\det(C)$. Does it hold something similar in the case with $n \gt m$? Or is it possible to define some lower bound for $\det(C)$? And if so, how to prove it?

If in the previous general case it doesn't hold, maybe it could help that, in my specific case $C$ and $A$ are two positive definite matrices and $B$ is a sparse matrix of zeros and ones. $A$ is also block diagonal. The only way I came up with is using Cauchy-Binet for the determinant of the product of rectangular matrices but I remained stuck with a summation involving the principal minors of the Cholesky factorization of $A$ times minors in $B$.

Comment: In which set does $x$ live?

Comment: In general, we would have $\text{det}(B'AB)=\text{det}(ABB')=\text{det}(A)\text{det}(BB')$

Comment: As concerning $\det(B'AB) = \det(A)\det(BB')$, if I'm not wrong, I would say that this is not true for a rectangular matrix $B$, since $B$ is a tall matrix $\det(BB')=0$, while in general $\det(B'AB) \neq 0$.

Comment: As concerning the set in which $x$ live is a compact non-convex set. (I hope this replies to your question)

Comment: How is the compact non-convex set defined?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I edited my question. The non-convex set is quite complicated and results from the definition of a nonlinear optimal control problem involving obstacle avoidance. But from your questions I get that in the general case it is not true that maximizing $\det(A)$ will lead to a maximization of $\det(C)$. Maybe if it exist some lower bound for the $\det(C)$ in this case, that could be useful.

Comment: I still do not know how you can hope to maximize the determinant without specifying the feasible region. Or, at least, of what form the feasible region is.

Comment: Please define convexity for matrix-valued functions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the variable matrix $A$ can vary within some set $\mathcal{A}$. Let the singular value decomposition of $B$ be
$$
B=UDV
$$
hence
$$
C=V^TD^TU^TAUDV
$$
hence
$$
|C|=|D^TXD|
$$
where $X=U^TAU$ and $X$ belongs to $\{U^TAU|A\in \mathcal{A}\}$. Now let
$$
D=\begin{bmatrix}
\hat D_{m\times m}\\0_{(n-m)\times m}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
\hat {X^{(11)}}_{m\times m}&\hat {X^{(12)}}_{m\times (n-m)}\\
\hat {X^{(21)}}_{(n-m)\times m}&\hat {X^{(22)}}_{(n-m)\times (n-m)}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
hence
$$
|C|=|D^TXD|=|\hat D^TX^{(11)}\hat D|=|\hat D|^2|X^{(11)}|.
$$
Therefore, if $B$ is not full-rank, $|C(x)|$ will always be zero, but if it is full-rank, then the maximization of $|C(x)|$ is directly the same of $|X^{(11)}|$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Very clear and useful!

Comment: Happy to help!${}$